# bedtool intersect to compare .vcf file to reference genome

Tags: vcf

I have a `.vcf` file generated using `samtools`. I want to know mutations in specific genes by comparing `.vcf` files with a reference genome. I cannot use the Ensembl VEP tool as my reference genome is not listed there. Can you please help?

Comment: Using SnpEff (http://snpeff.sourceforge.net/SnpEff_manual.html#databases) you can build custom annotation databases using the gff or gtf file. VEP also offers similar functionality https://asia.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/script/vep_custom.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter a VCF file, you might want to give **VCFtools** a try.

Here is the documentation : [VCFtools Manual](http://vcftools.sourceforge.net/man_latest.html)

I am not a specialist of this tool but you could do as the following. First build a bedfile with the chromosome names and positions of your genes (start and stop) such as this :

```
chr   start   stop   (name)   (score)   (strand)
```

Then it should work with this command line :

```
vcftools --vcf file.vcf --bed positions.bed --out filtered.vcf
```

The output will be a VCF filtered on the provided regions

Comment: thanks, I will try that!